# AS3 - Accessing protected properties from same package

Tags: actionscript-3, unit-testing, flashdevelop, protected, access-modifiers

I am trying to add unit tests into my project and I know before (in a previous project I worked on years ago) I was able to access protected variables and functions if I made the test class in the same package as the class I am testing. However I am having problems getting this working...

In my project folder I have a src folder which contains all the code and then I also have a test folder which contains all the test files. They have both been added as class paths to the project.

I have a class UIView which lives is com.test.view.UIView (within the src folder) and a test class UIViewTest which is in com.test.view.UIViewTest (in the test folder) but it is not able to access the protected properties of the UIView class.

Can someone help me? I am sure I'm missing something obvious. Both the classes say they have the same package. I am using FlashDevelop if that is relevant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You confuse different access modifiers: `protected` (visible in this class and in classes that inherited from this class) and `internal` (visible in the same package).